# Create dynamic less mixin setting property names

Tags: css, less

I want to create a less mixin to build up a number of margin/padding rules. I have been able to create the correct mixin for height, width, height percent and width percents. For example,

```
.widthX (@px) when (@px > 0) and (@px =< 30) {
    .width(@px);
    .widthX(@px - 1);
}

.widthX (@px) when (@px >= (30 + 5)) {
    .width(@px);
    .widthX(@px - 5);
}

.width (@px) { (~".w@{px}") { width: ~"@{px}px"; } }
```

This allows me to create explict widths or a series of width classes.  The following will create CSS classes for widths 1-30 in increments of 1 and then from 30-1215 in increments of 5.

```
.widthX (1215);
```

in the CSS it properly creates:

```
.w1 { width: 1px; }
.w2 { width: 2px; }
// 3-29 ommitted
.w30 { width: 30px; }
.w35 { width: 35px; }
.w40 { width: 40px; }
.w45 { width: 45px; }
// etc
```

I want to be able to create a similiar mixin for margin and padding plus allowing me to add each side as a parameter,

```
.marginX (@px,@side,@abbr) when (@px > 0) {
    .margin(@px,@side,@abbr);
    .marginX(@px - 1,@side,@abbr);
}

.margin (@px,@side,@abbr) { (~".w@{abbr}@{px}") { ~"width-${side}": ~"@{px}px"; } }
```

and call it as:

```
.marginX(100,"top","t");
```

to create margin-top classes for 1-100px. However, I keep getting syntax error on

```
{ ~"width-${side}": ~"@{px}px"; } }
```

I have tried numerous variations and they all keep failing.  I could, but really do not want to, create multiple mixins for each direction.  I am hoping someone might be able to provide some suggestions that will solve my problem.

I have found this similar post: [dynamic css properties in less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131175/dynamic-css-properties-in-less)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LESS does not currently support dynamic CSS properties. This lack of support for dynamic properties is one point of criticism which [some argue is an advantage of SASS over LESS](http://metaskills.net/2012/02/27/too-less-should-you-be-using-sass/).  There do exist pull requests on certain libraries (eg, [less.js](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/698)) which add this capability.

Otherwise, you are pretty much stuck doing what you didn't want to do, namely:

```
.margin (@px,@side,@abbr) when (@side = left) {
  (~".m@{abbr}@{px}") { margin-left: ~"@{px}px"; }
}
.margin (@px,@side,@abbr) when (@side = right) { 
  (~".m@{abbr}@{px}") { margin-right: ~"@{px}px"; }
}
```

Comment: Just for information ... I was recently playing with something like this trying to answer another similar question ... and came up with a couple workarounds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868042/using-an-argument-for-tag-name-in-less/15443008#15443008

Comment: As pointed out by Martin in his updated answer, the feature has been implemented in Less 1.6